# How to fix error while cloning branch git

Tags: laravel, git, github, laravel-5, git-bash

```
 git clone https://github.com/RezkyRizaldi/CostumRubber.git
 Cloning into 'CostumRubber'...
 remote: Enumerating objects: 53, done.
 remote: Counting objects: 100% (53/53), done.
 remote: Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
 remote: Total 10622 (delta 22), reused 33 (delta 14), pack-reused 10569
 Receiving objects: 100% (10622/10622), 69.05 MiB | 2.28 MiB/s, done.
 Resolving deltas: 100% (1687/1687), done.
 error: invalid path 
 'C:\Users\RULLRUBBER\Documents\CustomRubber\storage\logs/laravel-2020-06- 
 29.log'
 fatal: unable to checkout working tree
 warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
 You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
 and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Error begin when i cloning
I tried to find storage folder but its not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clone mostly worked; you have a local copy of the repo.  But git can't checkout the worktree because there's a filename in the root folder of the worktree that clashes with Windows filenaming rules.  (There's a second filename that I expect would clash with other systems, such as *nix; that makes me wonder if the corruption is deliberate.)

I don't know the context, but this is an issue that the repo maintainer should be resolving and if it were me, I'd need a very good reason to do anything with such a repo.  But if you must, you can manually checkout around it.

```
git reset HEAD -- ':!:./C*'
git checkout -- ':!:./C*'
```

If you then do a `git status` you'll see the two paths I'm talking about shown as staged deletions from the commit.  If you try to commit from this point, your commits will not contain whatever was at those paths, and it would look - to someone able to fully checkout the repo - as though you had deleted those files in your commit.

If those files contain important info, there should be ways to extract it - using git plumbing commands.